# Fully include Google web font in create-react-app build (without ejecting)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, google-fonts

I need to include a Google web font in the build of a React webapp using  create-react-app. This is, because the app will be served on a wifi without internet access. The most straightforward solution seems to be [google-fonts-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gabiseabra/google-fonts-webpack-plugin), but it needs a customized `webpack` config.

Is there any "simple" solution that downloads and includes all the web font resources automagically without the requirement to eject from create-react-app?

Comment: Why don't you just put it in the public font and access it with `@font-face` css?

Comment: I am currently using `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/...')` in my App.css but webpack won't pull the font files into the build. You mean by copying the contets of that import into my CSS file webpack will include the woff files etc. in the build?

Comment: You can download them as open type font. Download them and put them in the public folder then import it using `@import url('public...') whatever the relative url is

Answer (score 15):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

### 1. Importing font

For example, for using Roboto, do

```
yarn add typeface-roboto
```

or

```
npm install typeface-roboto --save
```

In index.js:

```
import "typeface-roboto";
```

There are npm packages for a lot of open source fonts and most of Google fonts. You can see all fonts [here](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces/tree/master/packages). All the packages are from that [project](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces/).

### 2. Download the font manually and add it to stylesheet

You can download fonts from [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com/)

[image: fonts.google.com page]

Now, you can put the font in `src/fonts/Lato.woff`, and use it in your `index.css`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: local('Lato'), url(./fonts/Lato.woff) format('woff');
}
```

For `ttf` font, you should give `truetype` instead of `ttf` as the parameter to the format

You can import this to your `index.js` to make it available

```
import './index.css';
```

You can do these in `App.css`, `App.js` as well. It's your preference.

Comment: Warning: Solution #1 supports only the Latin version of fonts. (2019/04)

Answer (score 3):

This answer is the updated version of @sudo bangbang's answer

### 1. Manually download the text package from Google Font

Head to any font that you wish to apply in your CSS, click the `Download family` to get a zip file.

[image]

Extract the zip file and move the folder into the src folder as below.

[image]

After that, refer to the below code, modify the `src` to the correct URL and put in the correct `format`. Here I used `truetype`, based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

> The available types are: "woff", "woff2", "truetype", "opentype", "embedded-opentype", and "svg".

The `font-family` attribute is the custom name. You can put any name you want.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'primary-font';
  src: url(./fonts//Sriracha/Sriracha-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.primary-font {
  font-family: primary-font;
}
```

### 2. Install the package `@fontsource`

Since **Typefaces project is now deprecated**, we can use the alternative package by the same author `FontSource`

Let me use `Poppins` as an example.
First, download the package

```
npm install @fontsource/poppins --save
```

Next import the package in your `index.js` file

```
import "@fontsource/poppins";
```

Then use it as you wish

```
.primary-font {
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
```

Supported font list is in this [Github repo directory.](https://github.com/fontsource/fontsource/blob/master/FONTLIST.md)

Comment: Great answer, can you add '@' before fontsource in npm install '@fontsource/poppins --save', as it is required and might help someone.

Comment: Sure, thanks for pointing it out :)